# mvc entity framework select bring related data from another table with condition statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relationship

I am developing an `MVC 5` with `Entity Framework`. I had import `Tables` from my `database`, and I have a table called `Users` with a relation one to many to another table called `Files`.

Here is (resumed) my two entitites.

```html
 public partial class Users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Uploads()
        {
            this.Files = new HashSet<Files>();
        }
    
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Files> Files { get; set; }
```

```html
 public partial class Files
    {
        public long File_id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        public int ProcessState_ID { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ProcessStates ProcessStates { get; set; }
        public virtual users Users { get; set; }
    }
```

When I do a `Select` from User Table, it bring (automatically) all relation data from `Files` table.

As I make `Logical Delete` in `Files` table. When I bring data from `User` tables, I need to use a `Condition` statement, to bring related records from `Files` table.

Is that Posible?

Thanks

Comment: I personally don't understand exactly what you would like to do. It seems to me that `Lazy Loading` is enabled hence why related data is returned. So are you saying that depending on your condition, you want return related records from db (enable lazy loading) or not return related records (disable lazy loading)? If so syntax is similar to: `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`
Set to true to enable or false to disable.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. What code are you using to retrieve the collection of Users?

Comment: Thanks...I forgot to use LazyLoading....